# Is There Any Way To Get The Actual Size Of Full Window In JavaScript / Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, liquid-layout

I'm trying to make a fluid layout for my site but the problem is that if a window is re-sized to be small before the page loads and then they maximize their window, the page is a small size, my question here is how would i get the width and height of a window at its full size even if the page is small.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var Height = $(document).height();
var Width = $(document).width();
});
```

This gives me the window height and width, i want the maximized size even if the window is small.

Comment: Even with media query?

Comment: I have gone with another alternative by just setting a min-width for most of my elements meaning my problem is gone, my problem was elemnts were colliding into each other becuase the window was too small.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you actually need to do is listen to the window's `resize` event and rearrange content as needed.

Alternatively, do it the modern way and use CSS Media Queries:

```
@media all and (max-width:480px) {
    /* styles for when the window is less than or equal to 480px wide */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Height = $("html").height();
var Width = $("html").width();
```

You could also try `body`, and it may even depend on the browser.  It is possible for some specially positioned elements to extend past the body, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to listen for window resize events:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Resize result window to see updated dimensions</p>
    Dimensions: <div id="debug"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateSize() {
    var $win = $(window);
    $('#debug').html($win.height() + ' x ' + $win.width());
}

$(window).resize(updateSize); // listen for window resize
$(updateSize); // call on page load to get initial size
```

Try it on jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TKAFc/

Answer (score 0):

If you need the screen size, you should use `screen.width` and `screen.height`.

You can subtract the "window borders" so you will have the useful area:

```
screen.width - (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth)
```

And the same for the height.

Comment: when i alert that i get "NaN"

Comment: I wrote outer with two Ts. Corrected now.